# Assign variable value from another component in *ngFor by click in angular 2

Tags: angular, input, selector, ngfor, pass-data

I trying in *ngFor pass object to another component, but passed only last object in table, but the object that was clicked should be displayed, how to solve this problem?

```
  <tr data-toggle="control-sidebar" *ngFor="let user of pagedItems">
      <td><control-sidebar [user]="user">
  </control-sidebar>{{ user.name }}</td>
```

and in another component view showing only last table row.

Comment: why are you passing `userDetails` instead of the `user` object ?

Comment: See this example. It shows how to pass a clicked object from `*ngFor` loop to another component.

https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt3/eplnkr.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are binding the `user` data to the `control-sidebar`:

`[user]="userDtails"`, the problem lies here.

Modify the code :

```
<tr data-toggle="control-sidebar" *ngFor="let user of pagedItems">
      <td (click)="getUser(user)"><control-sidebar [user]="user">
  </control-sidebar>{{ user.name }}</td>
```

Make sure you have defined the `getUser` method in your component class.

Notice that I have set: `[user]="user"`. SInce you want to pass the `user` object into `control-sidebar`.

Everything should work fine now.

**EDIT** :

Since you want to display the `user` that was clicked you can bind a method to the `(click)` handler and pass the `user` object. for example:

```
(click)="showUser(user)"
```

Comment: ohh excuse me, i made a mistake when i wrote post. I corrected it.in my code was same binding and i got result described above

Comment: You want the `user` object once you click on the `td`, right ?

Comment: may be it not work because i use table insted li like in your example?

Comment: Click handlers work for `td`. Edited answer. It should work fine.

Comment: I was inattentive, and forgot about elvis operator in component, your exapmle helped for me!Thanks!!